# How to add X-Robots-Tag "noindex" for multiple subdirectoris (from .htaccess / shared host)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I have a list of folders (named as numbers) located in domain.com/user/uploaded/ directory (for example: ../435/, ../580/ etc.).

I'm trying to use Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" from .htaccess for these folders, for example:

```
domain.com/user/uploaded/435/
domain.com/user/uploaded/580/
```

etc. for other folders within /user/uploaded/{number} folders.

That means that directory named /435/, /580/ etc. should have 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex' added.

I only have access to .htaccess (it's shared host / litespeed). I tried to add this:

```
<FilesMatch "^user/uploaded/?$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex"
</FilesMatch>
```

but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 2):

You should put a new `.htaccess` in `user/uploaded/` directory. In this file you will be able to specify your `.htaccess` rule

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex"
```

You don't need to use `FilesMatch` except if you want to target specific files.